# Unitarily equivalent operators have unitarily equivalent spectral measures

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

For every densely defined self-adjoint linear operator
$
A : \mathcal D(A) \subset H \to H
$
there is a unique spectral representation
$$
A = \int t \, dE_A(t)
$$
where $E_A$ is a spectral measure on $\mathbb R$. Now let $
B : \mathcal D(B) \subset H \to H
$ be another densely defined self-adjoint operator on $H$ with spectral measure $E_B$ which is unitarly equivalent to $A$ with unitary map $U$:
$$
AU=UB
$$

[This page](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Unitarily-equivalent_operators) is stating that the spectral measures are unitarily equivalent as well but I don't know how to prove it. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3):

The spectral measure of $A$ is uniquely determined by Stone's Formula:
$$
     \frac{1}{2}(E[a,b]+E(a,b))x \\= \lim_{\epsilon\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{a}^{b}\{(A-(u+i\epsilon)I)^{-1}x-(A-(u-i\epsilon)I)^{-1}x\} du
$$
If you replace $A$ by $UBU^{-1}$, you can work out how $U$ intertwines with $E_A$ and $E_B$.